# Trying to update a board but returns true

Tags: javascript, tetris

I'm trying to mutate my board but the function I declared doesn't work. Let me explain:

- I have a board of 18x24 and I'm trying to clear a row if it is full of elements(I unshift it so that the other row on top will fall to it's place)
- For that, I declared a function that should return the new board
- However, for some reason, the function does not return the board but instead, it returns a boolean value, which is unexpected.

Here's the initial board(borders should not be taken into account-shown with '#'-):

```
const myBoard = [
        Array(18).fill('#'),
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        Array(18).fill('#')
    ]
```

Here's the function:

```
function checkFilledRow(board) {
  let newBoard = []
  for (var row=1;row<board.length - 1;row++) {
    const currentRow = board[row]
    let newRow = []
    for (var i=1;i<currentRow.length - 1;i++) {
      if (currentRow[i] === '') {
        console.log(true)
        newRow = currentRow
        newBoard.push(newRow)
        break
      } else if (i === currentRow.length - 2) {
        newRow = ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#']
        newBoard.unshift(newRow)
        console.log(false)
      }
    }
  }
  return newBoard
}
```

What's the issue? What would you recommend? I did almost nothing with conditionals but I can't see a point in my code returning a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that since I forgot to add the top and the bottom borders, I would decrease the number of rows each turn. That what I solved by just this:

```
newBoard.unshift(Array(18).fill('#'))
newBoard.push(Array(18).fill('#'))
return newBoard
```